# what's incorrect in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

***There are two ways of making a gas condense: cooling it or putting it under pressure.***

Comment: It shouldn't be both italicized and in bold type.

Comment: why do you think something is wrong with it?

Comment: i think there is something wrong in this part 'a gas condense'

Comment: If you have trouble with "a gas condense" it's probably because you're misparsing it.  "Gas condense" is not a thing.  "A gas" is the object of the verb "making".  "Condense" is something else, the term for which I can't recall.  It doesn't modify "gas" (nor does "gas" modify it) but instead is sort of a second object for "making", indicating the transformation that is "made".

Answer (score 1):

The "or" is wrong.  "There are two..." requires a list of two things: thing #1 *and* thing #2.

If you were to say something like "to make a gas condense, you could cool it *or* put it under pressure", that would also be correct, but since you're making a list of two things, it must be "and".

Answer (score 0):

There's little wrong with the grammar. One might argue, perhaps, that the 'or' should be an 'and', fulfilling the claim that there are two ways of making the gas condense.

The Physics is wrong, though. A gas is defined as a substance above its critical point, so no amount of pressure will make it condense unless, *also*, the temperature is lowered below the critical point for that substance. This could be argued to be a linguistic mistake, because if 'vapour' is substituted for 'gas' the statement is correct.

Comment: The critical point of a gas depends on pressure, so the physics is entirely right. (E.g., at 2 atmospheres of pressure, the boiling point is 120°C.)

Comment: @Peter Shor You seem to be confusing boiling point and critical point. If you disagree, please give your source for your assertion that the critical point of a substance depends on pressure. [The assertion makes nonsense of the very notion of critical point, which is defined as the temperature above which a gas cannot be liquefied however high a pressure is applied to it.]

Comment: When I learned physics 30+ years ago, this distinction that some people make today between *vapor* and *gas* did not exist ... they were all called gasses. (Or at least, nobody taught me this distinction through 1 year of high school physics and 2.5 years of college physics), so I was totally confused by your answer, and thought you were confusing critical point and boiling point.

Comment: Interesting. The distinction was standard in the UK at that time, but maybe not in the US. The concept of critical point, and the name, has been around since the 1860s.